# I want to place boot on USB and boot RAID

Tags: linux, boot, usb, raid, grub

I have a Linux software RAID5 involving four disks (mdadm).

Here is my lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  5.5T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0  953M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0  5.5T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0 16.4T  0 raid5
    ├─md0p1 259:0    0    4G  0 md    [SWAP]
    ├─md0p2 259:1    0   30G  0 md    /
    └─md0p3 259:2    0 16.3T  0 md    /media/data
sdb           8:16   0  5.5T  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:17   0  953M  0 part
└─sdb2        8:18   0  5.5T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0 16.4T  0 raid5
    ├─md0p1 259:0    0    4G  0 md    [SWAP]
    ├─md0p2 259:1    0   30G  0 md    /
    └─md0p3 259:2    0 16.3T  0 md    /media/data
sdc           8:32   0  5.5T  0 disk
├─sdc1        8:33   0  953M  0 part
└─sdc2        8:34   0  5.5T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0 16.4T  0 raid5
    ├─md0p1 259:0    0    4G  0 md    [SWAP]
    ├─md0p2 259:1    0   30G  0 md    /
    └─md0p3 259:2    0 16.3T  0 md    /media/data
sdd           8:48   0  5.5T  0 disk
├─sdd1        8:49   0  953M  0 part  /boot
└─sdd2        8:50   0  5.5T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0 16.4T  0 raid5
    ├─md0p1 259:0    0    4G  0 md    [SWAP]
    ├─md0p2 259:1    0   30G  0 md    /
    └─md0p3 259:2    0 16.3T  0 md    /media/data
sde           8:64   1  7.2G  0 disk
└─sde1        8:65   1  953M  0 part
```

So when I ran into issues putting /boot inside the RAID (not realizing this was not possible), I created an identical 1GB partition at the front of each physical disk, intended to mirror the /boot across each one so that I could manually point grub2 to a secondary if the drive with the primary /boot failed.

However, what I would actually like to do instead is just put /boot on a flash drive or SD card and configure grub2 to look there instead. Then I don't even need those 1GB partitions on each drive, nor would I need to run grub-install to point grub to a different one etc. I could just create a backup image of the flash drive to burn to a new flash drive if the current one ever died. This would be fast and efficient and completely independent on of the physical disks.

Obviously I would prefer to have /boot inside the software RAID. However, since that is not possible, I would prefer to have it on a flash drive. This is what I have done to try and accomplish that:

[as root]

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sde1
mount /dev/sde1 /media/usbboot
grub-install --boot-directory=/media/usbboot /dev/sde1
umount /media/usbboot
reboot
```

[and use function key to boot off USB drive]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have started doing (since around 2013) was to create a RAID 1 for my `/boot` partition, across all my drives. 1GB on each drive is not that much. Grub will easily boot off of RAID 1, even if it has 4 devices.

I used to have my `/boot` on a USB, but I did not take good enough backups, and had to rebuild *anyways*. It's much nicer, and easier in the long run, to just do it the recommended way. Trust me.

Here is my layout:

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0   953M  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0 952.4M  0 raid1  /boot
├─sda2    8:2    0  18.6G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  37.2G  0 raid10 /
├─sda3    8:3    0   3.7G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0   7.5G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sda4    8:4    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5    8:5    0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md3   9:3    0   3.6T  0 raid10 /mnt/data
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0   953M  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0 952.4M  0 raid1  /boot
├─sdb2    8:18   0  18.6G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  37.2G  0 raid10 /
├─sdb3    8:19   0   3.7G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0   7.5G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sdb4    8:20   0     1K  0 part
└─sdb5    8:21   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md3   9:3    0   3.6T  0 raid10 /mnt/data
sdc       8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdc1    8:33   0   953M  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0 952.4M  0 raid1  /boot
├─sdc2    8:34   0  18.6G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  37.2G  0 raid10 /
├─sdc3    8:35   0   3.7G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0   7.5G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sdc4    8:36   0     1K  0 part
└─sdc5    8:37   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md3   9:3    0   3.6T  0 raid10 /mnt/data
sdd       8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdd1    8:49   0   953M  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0 952.4M  0 raid1  /boot
├─sdd2    8:50   0  18.6G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  37.2G  0 raid10 /
├─sdd3    8:51   0   3.7G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0   7.5G  0 raid10 [SWAP]
├─sdd4    8:52   0     1K  0 part
└─sdd5    8:53   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md3   9:3    0   3.6T  0 raid10 /mnt/data
```

Comment: How did you manage to put /boot on the RAID? I would think if it was possible to put /boot on a RAID1 then it would be possible to put it on a RAID5 too, yet I ran into constant issues booting the install no matter how I went about it. Finally, I concluded that maybe mdadm wasn't mounting the RAID prior to attempting to access /boot and therefore couldn't boot at all.

Comment: During the Debian Installer, I laid out my disks ahead of time. I'll edit to include my disk layout; but Grub loads RAID1 arrays just fine

Comment: Ahhh... It's probably because RAID1 is just a mirror. And so you are just mirroring the boot part across as many disks as you desire. I was not thinking outside the box, limiting myself to the conceptual 2 disks typically used for RAID1. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, one more question... I see you spliced out your / and swap and data into separate MD devices. Did you have any particular reasoning for that over a single MD device with them under it like the layout I have?

Comment: @JamesWilmoth My brain processes my layout easier, so that's the layout I always do